# /var/log has huge size because of snap

Tags: 20.04, snap, resize

Recently after I restarted my computer, it was giving "Low Disk Space Warning" . I did not care and because of that `/var/log` became %100 and I could not open my OS. So I deleted some files under `/var`.

Now it is %95 but it still gives that warning at beginning. You can see in picture after I clicked "examine" in that warning:

[image: after clicked examine button on the warning]

This is the size:

```
 canerveg@canerVegan  ~  df -h                              
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,7G     0  7,7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G   97M  1,5G   7% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   61G  6,9G   51G  12% /
tmpfs           7,7G  715M  7,0G  10% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,7G     0  7,7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2  946M  144M  737M  17% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1  975M   11M  964M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p6  149G   34G  107G  25% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p4  5,6G  5,2G  143M  98% /var
/dev/loop1      9,2M  9,2M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/99
/dev/loop3      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11316
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2066
/dev/loop7       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop5      163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop6      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop8       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop10     323M  323M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-6-stable/5
/dev/loop16      51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/542
/dev/loop17      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12398
/dev/loop18      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop22      51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop19     323M  323M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-6-stable/3
/dev/loop21     165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop23     5,5M  5,5M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/285
/dev/loop24     304M  304M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-5-stable/16
/dev/loop25     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
tmpfs           1,6G   28K  1,6G   1% /run/user/125
tmpfs           1,6G   48K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop26     338M  338M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime/228
/dev/loop12     100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11420
/dev/loop2       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
/dev/loop14     5,5M  5,5M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/287
/dev/loop20      11M   11M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/104
/dev/loop27     338M  338M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime/231
```

I did not know **/var** would be used so much. That is why i had given only 5.7 gb.

Biggest files in **/var**:

```
✘ canerveg@canerVegan  ~  sudo du -h --max-depth=6 /var | sort -h|tail -n25
6,1M    /var/cache/cracklib
6,4M    /var/lib/gdm3
6,6M    /var/cache/cups
8,1M    /var/cache/apparmor
8,9M    /var/lib/snapd/snapshots
12M /var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-focal-universe/64x64
12M /var/log
17M /var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-focal-universe
20M /var/lib/app-info
20M /var/lib/app-info/icons
28M /var/cache/app-info
28M /var/cache/app-info/cache
70M /var/lib/dpkg/info
75M /var/lib/dpkg
84M /var/cache/apt
148M    /var/cache
422M    /var/lib/snapd/seed
422M    /var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps
527M    /var/lib/apt
527M    /var/lib/apt/lists
1,8G    /var/lib/snapd/snaps
2,1G    /var/lib/snapd/cache
4,3G    /var/lib/snapd
4,9G    /var/lib
5,1G    /var
```

I think i can delete this safely:

```
2,1G    /var/lib/snapd/cache
```

but why do I have to delete those? If I knew it would go so high, I could give more size. Should I increase size because I have

```
/dev/nvme0n1p6  149G   34G  107G  25% /home
```

but it will be risky to shrink/resize.

Those are snaps:

```
 canerveg@canerVegan  ~  snap list --all    
Name                    Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
canonical-livepatch     9.6.2                       99     latest/stable    canonical✓  disabled
canonical-livepatch     9.7.2                       104    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
core                    16-2.51.1                   11316  latest/stable    canonical✓  core,disabled
core                    16-2.51.3                   11420  latest/stable    canonical✓  core
core18                  20210507                    2066   latest/stable    canonical✓  base,disabled
core18                  20210611                    2074   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804         3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145    latest/stable    canonical✓  disabled
gnome-3-28-1804         3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  161    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-34-1804         0+git.3556cb3               66     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  disabled
gnome-3-34-1804         0+git.3556cb3               72     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes       0.1-52-gb92ac40             1515   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes       0.1-50-gf7627e4             1514   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  disabled
notepad-plus-plus       8.1.2                       287    latest/stable    mmtrt       -
notepad-plus-plus       8.1.1                       285    latest/stable    mmtrt       disabled
snap-store              3.38.0-63-g766b86f          542    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  disabled
snap-store              3.38.0-64-g23c4c77          547    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd                   2.51.3                      12704  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
snapd                   2.51.1                      12398  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd,disabled
wine-platform-5-stable  5.0.3                       16     latest/stable    mmtrt       -
wine-platform-6-stable  6.0.1                       3      latest/stable    mmtrt       disabled
wine-platform-6-stable  6.0.1                       5      latest/stable    mmtrt       -
wine-platform-runtime   v1.0                        231    latest/stable    mmtrt       -
wine-platform-runtime   v1.0                        228    latest/stable    mmtrt       disabled
```

Here it removes old versions:
https://www.debugpoint.com/2021/03/clean-up-snap/

but I am thinking of removing snap completely. I can install whenever I need to install something from snap. What do you think of that?

software updater is downloading some updates now but it also decrease the size of /var. So, I cant download any apt bigger than 5 gb becase I have 5 gb /var?

[image: software updater]

I went to software center. clicked installed tab and removed all wines. There were 3 wines. I don't know why I installed those or an application maybe installed to be able to work.

Now it seems better:

```
 canerveg@canerVegan  ~  snap list --all
Name                 Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
canonical-livepatch  9.7.2                       104    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
canonical-livepatch  9.6.2                       99     latest/stable    canonical✓  disabled
core                 16-2.51.3                   11420  latest/stable    canonical✓  core
core                 16-2.51.1                   11316  latest/stable    canonical✓  core,disabled
core18               20210507                    2066   latest/stable    canonical✓  base,disabled
core18               20210611                    2074   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804      3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  161    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-28-1804      3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145    latest/stable    canonical✓  disabled
gnome-3-34-1804      0+git.3556cb3               66     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  disabled
gnome-3-34-1804      0+git.3556cb3               72     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes    0.1-50-gf7627e4             1514   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  disabled
gtk-common-themes    0.1-52-gb92ac40             1515   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
notepad-plus-plus    8.1.1                       285    latest/stable    mmtrt       disabled
notepad-plus-plus    8.1.2                       287    latest/stable    mmtrt       -
snap-store           3.38.0-63-g766b86f          542    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  disabled
snap-store           3.38.0-64-g23c4c77          547    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd                2.51.1                      12398  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd,disabled
snapd                2.51.3                      12704  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd

 canerveg@canerVegan  ~  cd /var/lib/snapd/snaps
 canerveg@canerVegan  /var/lib/snapd/snaps  ls
canonical-livepatch_104.snap  core18_2066.snap          gnome-3-34-1804_66.snap      notepad-plus-plus_285.snap  snapd_12704.snap
canonical-livepatch_99.snap   core18_2074.snap          gnome-3-34-1804_72.snap      notepad-plus-plus_287.snap  snap-store_542.snap
core_11316.snap               gnome-3-28-1804_145.snap  gtk-common-themes_1514.snap  partial                     snap-store_547.snap
core_11420.snap               gnome-3-28-1804_161.snap  gtk-common-themes_1515.snap  snapd_12398.snap

 canerveg@canerVegan  /var/lib/snapd/snaps  df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,7G     0  7,7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  2,5M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p5   61G  7,2G   51G  13% /
tmpfs           7,7G  733M  7,0G  10% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,7G     0  7,7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2  946M   93M  789M  11% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1  975M   11M  964M   2% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme0n1p6  149G   34G  107G  25% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p4  5,6G  3,8G  1,6G  71% /var
/dev/loop1      9,2M  9,2M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/99
/dev/loop3      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11316
/dev/loop4       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2066
/dev/loop7       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop5      163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop6      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop8       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop16      51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/542
/dev/loop17      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12398
/dev/loop18      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop22      51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop21     165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop23     5,5M  5,5M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/285
/dev/loop25     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
tmpfs           1,6G   28K  1,6G   1% /run/user/125
tmpfs           1,6G   60K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop12     100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11420
/dev/loop2       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
/dev/loop14     5,5M  5,5M     0 100% /snap/notepad-plus-plus/287
/dev/loop20      11M   11M     0 100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/104
 canerveg@canerVegan  /var/lib/snapd/snaps 
```

but I need to delete I think other snaps or apps or maybe even sourceslist.

Also:

```
 canerveg@canerVegan  ~  sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
 canerveg@canerVegan  ~  sudo apt-get autoremove                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
```

[image: disks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake you made was NOT about installing or using Snaps.

You made a classic advanced-new-user mistake: You over-partitioned.

Let's look at a snippet of your output:

```
    /dev/nvme0n1p5   61G  6,9G   51G  12% /
    /dev/nvme0n1p6  149G   34G  107G  25% /home
    /dev/nvme0n1p4  5,6G  5,2G  143M  98% /var
```

The Ubuntu Installer's recommendation of a single root partition (including /var and /home) would have resulted in something like...

```
    /dev/nvme0n1p4  217G   46G  171G  21% /
```

...and you would not be having any problems with full partitions.

Back up your data. Re-partition to match your actual usage. Reinstall.

Comment: Can i save by repartioning without reinstalling?

Comment: You can try. Sometime it's successful. Sometimes it's not. Be prepared for 'not' so your day is merely annoying instead of catastrophic.